# attr_accessor not accessible in accept_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

On my payments page there are certain variables such as card_number that I want to pass from the View to the Model but I do not want to store them in the db. I can usually easily achieve this by simply using attr_accessor but in this case the model is being passed in params through accepts_nested_attributes_for and for some reason the params are not being passed through:

in User.rb i have

```
  has_many :credit_cards

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :credit_cards
```

in the view file i have a nested form field, something like:

```
  blah blah
  <h2>Credit card</h2>
  <%= f.fields_for :credit_cards do |builder| %>
    <%= render "credit_card_fields", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>

  inside that
  <p>
    <%= f.label :test %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :test %>
  </p>
```

now back in credit_card.rb i have:

```
attr_accessor :test

before_create :show_me_test_param

private

def show_me_test_param
  raise "#{test}"
end
```

Now the strange thing is that when I try to save a record, it simply returns an empty exception. The param does not seem to have been passed through from User to CreditCard through accepts_nested_attributes_for?

The param being passed in is:

```
{"email"=>"name@example.com", "password"=>"pass123", "password_confirmation"=>"pass123", "credit_cards_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"test"=>"helllo this is the second attempt", "name_on_card"=>"first lastname", "card_number"=>"987498742897", "card_verification_value"=>"232", "expiry_date"=>"2141"}}}
```

Does anyone know whats going on? Does accepts_nested_attributes_for work with attr_accessor?

Comment: Have you tried debugging in the controller to see if the params hash has what you think it should?

Comment: hey yes i have, it works if i place the field on the parent model and do it there. It seems that it just doesnt work under accepts_nested but surely if thats the case then others would have noticed that too

Comment: What does the params hash look like? Could you please post the params hash as seen by the User controller?

Comment: Have you tried adding the attr_accessor on the User model instead of the CreditCard model? also, have you tried "attr_accessor :credit_card_attributes" on the User model? the _attributes may be needed if you are protecting from mass assignment

Comment: Hey thanks blake, i tried that but if I put this into the creditcard model then it change anything but if I add it to the user.rb model then it skips the entire before_create callback and doesnt add a creditcard to the user!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has messed me up several times in the past! Params for nested objects come to the controller with the key `model_name_attributes` which gets passed to the new or update_attributes method of the model in the controller.

So you'll need to add `:credit_card_attributes` to your `attr_accessor` to allow that key to be passed in.

Comment: If you look at the param I think it should be :credit_cards_attributes rather than :credit_card_attributes. If I put this into the creditcard model then it doesnt do anything but if I add it to the user.rb model then it skips the entire callback and doesnt add a creditcard to the user!? Any ideas? Incredibly frustrating isnt it

Comment: Having same issue, can you show how you have this config'd now?